# Как сделать правильные URL'ы

Tags: php

Всем привет.
Есть ссылки такого рода

```
http://mydomen.com/search.php?q=love+film
http://mydomen.com/search.php?q=prostokey+zaposi
http://mydomen.com/search.php?q=key1+key2+key3+key4
```

Как реализовать чтобы при поиске первое слово бралось и стали ссылки такого рода

```
http://mydomen.com/love/love+film
http://mydomen.com/prostokey/prostokey+zaposi
http://mydomen.com/key1/key1+key2+key3+key4
```

Необходимо реализацию только на php.
Искал в инете, но не смог найти.
СПасибо

Comment: почему не 

 * http://mydomen.com/love/film
 * http://mydomen.com/prostokey/zaposi
 * http://mydomen.com/key1/key2+key3+key4

?

Comment: Хм, а почему бы и нет.. Можно попробовать. А как реализовать?

Comment: а где сложность ? в смысле вы не можете сделать роутер или не можете преобразовать ссылки в выводе ?

Comment: Хм, если бы я могу реализовать все через php то не попросил бы помощи...

Answer (score 3):

```
//.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

//index.php
<?php
$uri_deep = 0; // глубина в подпапках, по умолчанию 0 если сайт лежит в корне

$route = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
$route = array_filter($route);
array_splice($route, 0, $uri_deep);
if (empty($route[0])) { $route[0] = 'index'; }

//var_dump($route);
?>
```

получите массив $route примерно такого вида, уже с фильтрами от пустых параметров и слеша в конце:

```
http://domain.com/module/controller/parametr1/parametr2////parametrN/

[0] => module
[1] => controller
[2] => parametr1
[3] => parametr2
[4] => parametrN
```

ну а далее делаете что хотите с массивом, можно как то так:

```
$mod_path = '/module_path/';
$exe_mod_file = $mod_path . $route[0] . '.php'; // полный путь к модулю

if (file_exists($exe_mod_file)) { Include_once($exe_mod_file); }
else { header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"); Include_once ($mod_path . '404.php'); }
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я немного запутался...
Куда и что нужно поставить?
Можете по пунктам написать?
Спасибо
1. сделать .htaccess
А дальше что куда? Я просто не силен в php

Comment: htaccess - это не php. Это такой файл конфигурации к apache, который запускает ваши php скрипты (конечно, можно ещё их запускать и на iis, но это для ценителей).
Этот файл нужно положить в корневой каталог.

Comment: Про использование .htaccess - это я знаю.
А что дальше делать со скриптами, которые тут есть?

Comment: 1) Создайте файлы: .htaccess и index.php с содержанием выше

2) Массив $route будет содержать адрес который пользователь ввёл в строку браузера

3) Исходя из этого массива, путём `include_once();` подключаете нужный вам скрипт с нужными параметрами поиска

Это сложновато объяснить в 2х строках, можете погуглить "MVC" и конкретно это видео: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRacpbuG6Es

Эти 40 минут видео были самыми ценными знаниями которые я получил