# Куки и слеш в конце адресной строки

Tags: php, cookie

Привет, использую стандартную свою наработку, все запросы через .htaccess направляю на роутер и далее `explode` «паршу» URI, описывал это: [вот-тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/276144/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-url-%D1%8B?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=276153#276153). Для меня наличие или отсутствие слеша в конце не принципиально, тк ипользую `array_filer`, и `array_splice` что позволяет верно парсить даже такие урлы как:

```
http://domain.com//contoller////model////view/paramtrN///
```

Но вот незадача: нужно поставить куку а она ставится только тогда когда слеш в конце отсутствует, тоесть:

```
http://domain.com/test/setcookie  => кука поставится
http://domain.com/test/setcookie/ => кука НЕ поставится
```

Вывода до setcookie конечно никакого нет, ставить пробовал по разному:

```
$n = setcookie ('deonis', 'foobar1', 1577836800);
// причем $n в обоих случаях возвращает true
// что как бы намекает на то что она ставится но ее не видно
// или
header('Set-cookie: deonis=bar123');
```

Подскажите где я оступился? Мне нужно чтобы кука вставала вне зависимости от слеша в конце, с любого места http://domain.com/ она была видна. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: смотрите что браузеру присылается в заголовках (chrome dev tools/firebug)

Comment: `/test/setcookie` - при таком урле кука будет доступна строго для `test/*`, а при таком `/test/setcookie/` - строго для `test/setcookie/*`. Вроде бы более чем очевидный момент. Задайте входной параметр `$path`.

Comment: @Равнодушный, более чем очевидный момент, но всё же Вы не могли бы продемонстрировать верную установку куков для всех директорий домена в целом из директории `test/setcookie/` предположим домен: `homedomen.net` буду Вам безумно благодарен тк пробовал «повякому»

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Устанавливайте четвёртым параметром путь для куки.

```
setcookie ('deonis', 'foobar1', 1577836800, '/');
```

Всё должно заработать